# Can I connect Power BI service to AWS RDS without data gateway?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, powerbi, amazon-rds

Can I connect Power BI service to public/internet-accessible AWS RDS without using a data gateway?
I found in AWS docs that it can be done, but when I tried it didn't work.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/using-power-bi-with-aws-cloud/connecting-the-microsoft-power-bi-service-to-aws-data-sources.html